# BroadCast de notificação quando dispositivo Android está adormecido

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Tenho uma *activity* que chama uma função de uma classe (service) que cria um `intent = NEW INTENT("MEU_BROADCAST")` e também um *AlarmManager*. Dentro da classe *BroadCast* eu chamo um *activity* que cria um notificação.

Tudo funcionando perfeitamente, o meu problema é que quero que ele desperte mesmo quando o usuário clique no botão *power* (*sleep*), pois ele não desperta se estiver adormecido, só quando o usuário clica no power para ligar a tela.
Tentei usar o *PowerManager* só que não está funcionando!
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Essa função é da minha classe que não estende de nada! é apenas uma função que eu chamo via um OBJETO

```
public void gravarAlertaDeEvento(Context ctx, int alarmId, int mHour, int mMinute, boolean repeat, Calendar calendar, String titulo, String evento, boolean som)
{
    //Intent intentAlarme = new Intent(ctx, Alarme.class);
    Intent intentAlarme = new Intent("EXECUTAR_ALARME");
    //intentAlarme.setAction("Start");
    intentAlarme.putExtra("id_evento", ""+alarmId);
    intentAlarme.putExtra("musica", som);
    intentAlarme.putExtra("titulo_evento", titulo); //Insere titulo do evento salvo
    intentAlarme.putExtra("evento", evento);    //insere info do evento salvo
    //PendingIntent enviarAlarme = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, alarmId, intentAlarme, 0);
    PendingIntent enviarAlarme = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, alarmId, intentAlarme, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if(repeat)
    {
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), enviarAlarme);
    }else
    {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), enviarAlarme); 
    }   
}
```

Minha classe Service:

```
public class GerandoNotificacao extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    try {

        String titulo = intent.getStringExtra("titulo_evento");
        String assunto = intent .getStringExtra("evento");

        NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notific = new Notification(R.drawable.calendar2, "Evento", System.currentTimeMillis());

        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("musica", false))
        {
            notific.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.alarme);
        }           

        notific.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notific.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notific.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notific.ledARGB = R.color.seaGreen;

        notific.vibrate = new long[]{ 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250, 500 };

        int idEvento = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("id_evento")); //pegando id da notificação

        Intent activityAbrir = new Intent(this, EditarEvento.class);
        activityAbrir.putExtra("tela", "eventos");
        activityAbrir.putExtra("p_c", ""+idEvento);
        activityAbrir.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   

        //PendingIntent para executar a Activity se o usuário selecionar a notificação
        PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, idEvento, activityAbrir, 0);

        notific.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), titulo, assunto, pendInt);
        notManager.notify(idEvento, notific);       

        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alert: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Minha classe WakeupfullBroadcastReceved

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

    Intent intet = new Intent(c, GerandoNotificacao.class); //Chamando a classe notificação
    intet.putExtra("id_evento", i.getStringExtra("id_evento"));      //insere id do evento (banco de dados)
    intet.putExtra("musica", i.getBooleanExtra("musica", false));
    intet.putExtra("titulo_evento", i.getStringExtra("titulo_evento")); //Insere titulo do evento salvo
    intet.putExtra("evento", i.getStringExtra("evento"));   //insere info do evento salvo

    /*try {
        this.finalize();
    } catch (Throwable e) { Log.i("Erro borad: ", e.getMessage());  }*/
    startWakefulService(c, intet);        
}
```

Meu Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="br.com.AlarmeEvento.Alarme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="EXECUTAR_ALARME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quem tem que possuir uma Wake Lock para manter a CPU acordada é o broadcast receiver e não o código que agenda o alarme junto ao AlarmManager. Sugiro que seu broadcast receiver seja uma subclasse de [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html). Caso o disparo do alarme (som a ser tocado, etc.) seja executado dentro de um serviço à parte e não diretamente em `onReceive()`, o serviço antes de finalizar deve chamar `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent)` para que a Wake Lock seja liberada.

Comment: Dois problemas: a linha `intet.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` deve ser removida e a chamada `am.setRepeating()` usa o parâmetro `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` duas vezes (não deve usar na segunda vez, e sim um valor em milissegundos para o intervalo de repetição: se for diário, esse valor deve ser por exemplo `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` que é a quantidade de milissegundos em um dia). Algo me diz que sua classe `GerandoNotificacao` é uma `Activity` e não um `Service`, ela deveria ser um `Service`. Poste o código dela também na pergunta. Inclua uma linha `Log.i()` nela e veja se é executada.

Comment: Esse calendar.getTimeInMillis() é do calendário que passei via parametro, logo acho que não é um problema!
Ele tem esses dois pois talvez o usuário queria que repita o alarme logo eu tenho um setRepeat() e um set() normal! @Piovezan

Comment: Você parou para entender para que servem esses dois parâmetros? O primeiro é a hora que o alarme deve disparar e o segundo é o INTERVALO DE REPETIÇÃO. É um intervalo que o AlarmManager vai esperar antes de disparar de novo, e não uma data. Se e a sua intenção é que o alarme repita a cada dia na mesma hora, use o valor que eu falei.

Comment: No seu serviço no lugar do método `onStart()` que é obsoleto e não é mais chamado pelo sistema, use `onStartCommand()`. Assim: `@Override public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { super.onStartcommand(intent, flags, startId);` e faça-o retornar qualquer coisa, por exemplo `return START_NOT_STICKY;`.

Comment: E na boa, se isso funcionar, aceite a minha resposta clicando no ícone de aceitar a resposta como nesse exemplo: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Comment: @Piovezan funcionou perfeitamente no celular só meu irmão! Só no meu que não! Acho que a Sony tá bloqueando kkkkkk! Mas vou fazer outros teste com outros celulares! Agora meu problema é: se o usuário deletar o evento antes de acontecer eu preciso cancelar esse alarme! Como eu deveria proceder, vc sabe?

Comment: Se o problema é outro, abra uma outra pergunta. O site funciona assim: uma pergunta por problema. :)