# Cancelando um AlarmManager/BroadCast

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Seguinte, não sei qual devo cancelar pra não ser executado, mas creio que seja o `AlarmManager`!
Tenho uma classe que registra um `AlarmManager` com `Intent("BROADCAST")` para executar em um horário específico, quando esse `AlarmManager` é executado ele chama um classe que estende de `WakefullBroadcastReceived`, e quando esse receve é executado ele chama uma classe tipo `Service` que gera uma notificação!

Todo o código das informações está nesse link(outro chamado que foi resolvido): 
[BroadCast de notificação quando dispositivo Android está adormecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19186/broadcast-de-notificacao-quando-dispositivo-android-esta-adormecido/19189?noredirect=1#comment35615_19189)

Minha pergunta agora é: como cancelar a execução desse evento caso o usuário exclua o evento antes dele ter ocorrido (fazer com que ele não desperte/execute o `Broadcast`/`AlarmManager`)
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui! apenas é preciso criar um `intent` com as mesmas informações do que foi passado para criação. com todos os `putExtras()` que foi colocado e tals! obrigado!